# How to make the actual table adjust its size to the QTableWidget container?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I do not even know how to ask this question. I have the following table:

[image]

You can see how the QTableWidget is selected, but the actual table is smaller. How can I make the table to be the same size of the QTableWidget container?

I am using QT-Designer.

Thanks!

Comment: This is from code, not sure designer gives this option. http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9761

Comment: Can you post the code? Absent the code, my best recommendation is to look at SizePolicy and consider either Expanding or MinimumExpanding. You can also set SizeHints on the items via a delegate

Comment: Hi Viv. That is the answer. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

from Qt Designer there are

```
horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection
```

and

```
verticalHeaderStretchLastSection
```

properties on QTableWidget.